# How do I issue a warning in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: debug, warnings

I'm trying to debugging a plug in that's misbehaving. I don't have a good setup for debugging and developing wordpress, so I just want to output the values of some variables to the rendered page. Is that possible? How do you issue a warning or some sort of message?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, wherever you're working on data that's output, just use var_dump($whatever_variable). You can also use print_r($a_variable)